# How many times has "Make It So" been demanded by anyone other than Picard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

In Star Trek, how many times has

[image: "Make It So"]

been demanded by anyone other than Picard?  I'm looking for a complete list.

The question is not necessarily exclusive to the *The Next Generation*.

Comment: Picard: "How many times has someone ended a command with 'make it so'?  You don't know?!  Do you know how to find out?  Good - then **make it so!**"

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105874/how-many-times-has-make-it-so-been-demanded-by-picard-in-one-episode

Comment: I think a commanding officer telling someone to do something would be best described as an "order" rather than "demand".

Comment: @DJClayworth : Yep. An order is a type of demand.  I chose to use a more general word because, in the other instances I am seeking, the speaker may not necessarily be a *commanding officer issuing an order to a subordinate.*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I won't force you to read the whole answer as it is a little bit long, so to cut to the chase:

## 'Make it so' was used as a demand 11 times in Star Trek by someone other than Picard

---

Well, you said you wanted a complete list, so here goes:

- Data in 'Gambit Pt 2' and *Generations*
- LaForge in *TNG* 'Angel One'
- Riker in TNG* 'Contagion', 'Interface', 'The Battle', 'Darmok' and 'The Best of Both Worlds Pt I & Pt II' (once in Pt I, twice in Pt II)
- Quark (sort of) in *DS9* 'The House of Quark:

  > QUARK: Go ahead, kill me. That's why I'm here, isn't it, to be killed? Well, here I am, so go ahead and do it. You all want me to pick up that sword and try to fight him, don't you? But I don't have a chance and you know it. You only want me to put up a fight so your precious honour will be satisfied. Well, I'm not going to **make it so** easy for you.

and again in 'The Maquis Pt II':

> QUARK: Then I'll **make it so** simple that even a Vulcan can understand.

- Dukat in *DS9* 'Wrongs Darker Than Death Or Night':

  > DUKAT: Basso! That's enough. Welcome to Terok Nor. I hope your stay here will be a pleasant one. I assure you, I will do everything possible to **make it so**.
- Worf (Mirror) in *DS9* 'Shattered Mirror':

  > WORF: And while you dispose of the Intendant, I will dispose of the rebels. **Make it so**!
- Hrothgar in *VOY* 'Heroes and Demons':

  > HROTHGAR: Always with you it is time to sleep. Perhaps you have forgotten that the work of a warrior is battle not rest. You would do well to learn from Lord Schweitzer. This was a beautiful hall once, before Grendel. You will **make it so** again. You have our thanks.
- Plasus in *TOS* 'The Cloud Miners':

  > PLASUS: We'll do everything possible to make it so. Come, gentlemen.
- Jameson in *TNG* 'Too Short a Season':

  > JAMESON: A sensible precaution, Picard. Make it so.

and special mention to Picard Jr in *TNG* 'Rascals'.

From the above, it's fair to say that Riker says it **a lot!**

## In total, this is 16 instances of the phrase 'make it so' said in the main Star Trek materials by people other than Picard

However, that's just the number of times the *phrase* has been used, not the number of times it has been *demanded*.  From the above list, **11** of those are actual demands using that phrase.  To get to that figure, I have included:

- Data x 2
- LaForge x 1
- Riker x 6
- Worf x 1
- Jameson x 1

which = 11

Comment: I am now an expert on the use of 'make it so' in Star Trek!

Comment: A few of these are a bit of a reach...

Comment: Now I'm curious how many times Picard has said it...

Comment: I like the earliest use by Plasus.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman see here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105874/how-many-times-has-make-it-so-been-demanded-by-picard-in-one-episode/105876#105876

Comment: @TheDoc: Interesting, though I was talking about how many times over the entire series + movies, not just most in one episode.  I'd make it a new question, but I don't really *need* to know, just curious.

Comment: Personally I would only look at those where "make it so" was used as a command. Many of those instances cited are not a command

Comment: @WayneInYak As I have made quite clear in my answer, I have identified all the uses of 'make it so' in Star Trek canon, but I have then ignored those which were not used as a command in the count of 11; perhaps you overlooked this?

Comment: And one [(NSFW) just f'n go](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/1fbf5106-858c-4f35-8bc1-fe286fbb0d68) from Nanette in Black Mirror.

Answer (score 9):

Ignoring cases where a character said the sequence of words but not the phrase itself with same meaning (example "I'm not going to make it so easy"), we have

**Riker, in "Contagion", "Best of Both Worlds Part 1", "Best of Both Worlds Part 2" (twice), and "Darmok"**

**Data, in "Gambit Part 2"**

The above cases are heavily influenced by Picard.   The following one isn't,  however,  as far as we know, since it comes from Worf in the Mirror Universe (where we don't know of Picard's existence, the Terrans are weak and slaves, and Worf as Regent most certainly never served under Picard):

**Worf, in *DS9*'s "Shattered Mirror"**.

## Edit:

There are three more,  pointed out by N_Soong.  I don't mean to steal them,  but now that I know about then,  I don't see how I can not edit them in here.  Please give him an upvote too.

**La Forge in "Angel One"**

**Riker, in "The Battle"**

**Data, in *Generations*.**

## \Edit

I was going to edit in the quotes, but it doesn't add much, in my opinion since the quote in all cases is

> Make it so

(duh) with essentially the context not adding much.

That is **ten** times,  by my current count,  but there may be a few more.

Honorable mention in "Samaritan Snare", I believe Grebnedlog was just too dumb to get it right:

> GREBNEDLOG [on viewscreen]: Things to **make it go**.
>
> RIKER: We will use our tractor beam to tow you to the nearest base.
>
> GREBNEDLOG [on viewscreen]: He can **make it go**.

(jk)

Additional side remark which doesn't answer the question but is fun:  Capt. Jellico's pseudo-equivalent is **Get it done**, which he says twice in one episode and only to Riker who he thinks is not "a particularly good first officer."

Comment: Note, @The_Doc's "Interface" isn't valid.   The quote is *And all the hoping in the world wouldn't make it so.*

Comment: As of this moment, @The_Doc (N_Soong) also has ten, but for the wrong reason.  He missed the two in "BOBW2", and wrongly counted "Interface"

Comment: @TheDoc, anyone can edit to make it so.   :)  OK, now we agree.  Except you really didn't explain which of your list are invalid.

Comment: @TheDoc, no, now you're just trying to win.   Hrothgar is not valid.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/bXB7Y4AFBcRYte6P7