# How many times has "Make It So" been demanded by Picard in one episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

Related: [How many times has "Make It So" been demanded by anyone other than Picard?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105867/how-many-times-has-make-it-so-been-demanded-by-anyone-other-than-picard)

## How many times has "Make It So" been demanded by Picard in one episode?

Answer (score 8):

## 5 times in 'Cause and Effect'...

According to [the script](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/218.htm), we have:

> PICARD: Make it so, Mister Data
>
> PICARD: Mister Worf, make it so.
>
> PICARD: Make it so, Mister Worf.
>
> PICARD: Make it so, Mister Worf.

and

> PICARD: Make it so, Mister Worf.

No, I'm not joking; in the episode, we have a temporal loop, so Picard says the same line four times!

## ...but

They are exceptional circumstances though and, to be fair, the spirit of the question probably didn't mean that.  So, in light of this, the most number of times Picard demands 'Make it so' *without* a temporal loop causing it is **3** in 'The Loss':

> PICARD: Make it so, Ensign.

and

> PICARD: Make it so.

and

> PICARD: Make it so.

Note that Picard also says 'Make it so' three times in 'Clues':

> PICARD: Make it so.

and

> PICARD: Doctor, Commander, **make it so**. Meanwhile, we will maintain our present course. If there is something wrong with Data, we don't want him to be aware of our suspicions.

and finally

> PICARD: **Make it so**. And put out a hazard advisory to Starfleet. Ensign, set a course to Evadne Four.

Fun fact: when researching this, I found that the phrase is used in 64 episodes of *TNG*!

Comment: @ThePopMachine added the two instances of when he says it three times in an episode *not* because of a temporal loop ;)

Comment: 64 is actually surprisingly low.